# Subversion Configuration

Tags: svn, subversive

I've downloaded subversion server and client RPM's from Collabnet, and installed it. It was unpacked into opt/CollabNet_Subversion directory.

But when I try to run  `/bin/svn` a message "this is not a working copy" is shown. I'm trying to find documentation onlyne, but it seems to be poor.

Must I make sth or run a script to configure it?

I'm a rookie in Subversion. Thanks for helping!

PS: System: Linux Suse 11.2
SVersion: 1.7.6-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use Subversion (or any version control software), you must:

- Create a repository that will hold your files. (You use the `svnadmin create` command to do that.)
- In **another** directory, you checkout from the repository to a *working directory*. You use the `svn checkout` command for that).
- You do your work in your *working directory*
- When you've completed your work, you *commit* or *checkin* your changes back into the repository. (You use the `svn commit` command for that).

For creating the repository, take a look at [Chapter 5](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html) of the [Subversion on line manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html). Then, go through [chapter #1](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.html) and [chapter #2](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.html) to get the basic understanding how Subversion (and version control) works and use the repository you created to help you learn how to use Subversion.

That will give you a general understanding you'll need. Once you get the basics out of the way, you can go through the rest of the book.

Answer (score 2):

"this is not a working copy" means exactly that. You need to "checkout" a repository into a working copy before you can perform SVN operations on it. SVN can tell it is a working copy because of the `.svn` folder inside it.

For more info, see: [Creating a Working Copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.initial.html)

> Most of the time, you will start using a Subversion repository by
>   performing a checkout of your project. Checking out a directory from a
>   repository creates a working copy of that directory on your local
>   machine. Unless otherwise specified, this copy contains the youngest
>   (that is, most recently created or modified) versions of the directory
>   and its children found in the Subversion repository.

I find the documentation online quite good. Give a good read to [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html) and see if you still have questions after that.